# Simulink vector scope giving me a zero signal

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, simulink

ok, I have a modulated wave having a timeseries variable that has a plot which 
looks like this in matlab

[image: http://i.imgur.com/K1cGs5b.png]

I go to Simulink software and then load my time series variable 'z' in workspace and in my editor I load this 'z' using a from workspace block from sources in library . now i view my signal using a vector scope as well as time scope but my output looks like this

[image: http://i.imgur.com/K1cGs5b.png]

why am I getting this , why can't i get my original wave as seen by matlab ?
Please help ...

Comment: What solver and time step are you using? Is `z` defined as a timeseries object? have you ticked the checkbox in the From Workspace block to interpolate the data? Why are you using a vector scope as opposed to a normal Simulink scope? Does the output look the same in a normal Simulink scope?

Comment: solver is discreet. step size is .36 as my run time is 18 seconds . yes z is a timeseries object . I have ticked the interpolate data checkbox. when I used a normal scope I get an error with the step size . I then changed it to 1 but then it would show me an error box that suddenly vanishes in a second , computer gives me the error beep sound and i don't get any output

Comment: What error do you get with the step size? You need to fix that error first and then the signal should display correctly on the scope. It's difficult to say more without seeing the model, but I suspect you need to reduce the step size or use a variable-step solver.

Comment: What is the sample time of your timeseries object `z`? You want the step size of your model to be less or equal to that value.